# Add syntax into if statement in PHP

Tags: php

I want to add these code into if statement in php. Can it be done?

```
<script>
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('#first_container').vegas({
        color: '<?php echo $wa[custom_79];?>',
        delay: <?php echo $wa[custom_80];?>,
        transitionDuration: <?php echo $wa[custom_133];?>,
        timer: false,
        transition: null,
        slides: [
            <?php if ($wa[custom_82] != "" && $wa[custom_83] == "1") { $wa[custom_82] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_82]);?>
                {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_82];?>'},
            <?php }
            if ($wa[custom_84] != "" && $wa[custom_85] == "1") { $wa[custom_84] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_84]);?>
                {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_84];?>'},
            <?php }
            if ($wa[custom_86] != "" && $wa[custom_87] == "1") { $wa[custom_87] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_87]);?>
                {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_86];?>'},
            <?php }
            if ($wa[custom_88] != "" && $wa[custom_89] == "1") { $wa[custom_89] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_89]);?>
                {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_88];?>'},
            <?php }
            if ($wa[custom_90] != "" && $wa[custom_91] == "1") { $wa[custom_91] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_91]);?>
                {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_90]?>'},
            <?php } 
            if ($wa[custom_92] != "" && $wa[custom_93] == "1") { $wa[custom_93] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_93]);?>
                {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_92]?>'},
            <?php }
            if ($wa[custom_94] != "" && $wa[custom_95] == "1") { $wa[custom_95] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_95]);?>
                {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_94];?>'},
            <?php } 
            ?>
            <? if ($wa[custom_94] != "" && $wa[custom_95] == "1") { $wa[custom_95] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_95]);?>
                {src:'images/1-Hov-Lean-1800px-X600px.jpg'},
            <? } ?>
            <? if ($wa[custom_96] != "" && $wa[custom_95] == "1") { $wa[custom_95] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_95]);?>
                {src:'images/1-Angkor-1800px-X-600px.jpg'},
            <? } ?>
            <? if ($wa[custom_98] != "" && $wa[custom_95] == "1") { $wa[custom_97] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_97]);?>
                {src:'images/Home-Pages-Angkor-PC.png'},
            <? } ?>
            {src:'images/Home-Pages-Peakbond.png'}
        ],
</script>

<?php if ($wa[custom_132] == "1") { ?>
    <a href="#" class="previous hidden-xs" style="visibility: visible;"></a>
    <a href="#" class="next hidden-xs" style="visibility: visible;"></a>
<?php } ?>
```

It should be like this

```
<?php
if($_COOKIE["size"]>800)
  echo "I want to put those code inside here";
else
  echo "Not decide yet";
?>
```

Can this be done because i want to display different image banner in the slideshow based on the resolution of the device monitor. Thanks

Comment: Where do you set the cookie? Where are you using a banner?

Comment: I set the cookie in the javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you are after? If not, please clarify your requirements and correct the syntax errors in your question.

```
<?php if($_COOKIE["size"]>800) {
    echo '<script>var iqmal = true;</script>';
    if ($wa[custom_132] == "1") {
        echo '
            <a href="#" class="previous hidden-xs" style="visibility: visible;"></a>
            <a href="#" class="next hidden-xs" style="visibility: visible;"></a>
        ';
    }
?>

<script>
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    if( iqmal ) {
        $('#first_container').vegas({
            color: '<?php echo $wa[custom_79];?>',
            delay: <?php echo $wa[custom_80];?>,
            transitionDuration: <?php echo $wa[custom_133];?>,
            timer: false,
            transition: null,
            slides: [
                <?php if ($wa[custom_82] != "" && $wa[custom_83] == "1") { $wa[custom_82] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_82]);?>
                    {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_82];?>'},
                <?php }
                if ($wa[custom_84] != "" && $wa[custom_85] == "1") { $wa[custom_84] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_84]);?>
                    {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_84];?>'},
                <?php }
                if ($wa[custom_86] != "" && $wa[custom_87] == "1") { $wa[custom_87] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_87]);?>
                    {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_86];?>'},
                <?php }
                if ($wa[custom_88] != "" && $wa[custom_89] == "1") { $wa[custom_89] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_89]);?>
                    {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_88];?>'},
                <?php }
                if ($wa[custom_90] != "" && $wa[custom_91] == "1") { $wa[custom_91] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_91]);?>
                    {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_90]?>'},
                <?php } 
                if ($wa[custom_92] != "" && $wa[custom_93] == "1") { $wa[custom_93] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_93]);?>
                    {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_92]?>'},
                <?php }
                if ($wa[custom_94] != "" && $wa[custom_95] == "1") { $wa[custom_95] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_95]);?>
                    {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_94];?>'},
                <?php } 
                ?>
                <? if ($wa[custom_94] != "" && $wa[custom_95] == "1") { $wa[custom_95] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_95]);?>
                    {src:'images/1-Hov-Lean-1800px-X600px.jpg'},
                <? } ?>
                <? if ($wa[custom_96] != "" && $wa[custom_95] == "1") { $wa[custom_95] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_95]);?>
                    {src:'images/1-Angkor-1800px-X-600px.jpg'},
                <? } ?>
                <? if ($wa[custom_98] != "" && $wa[custom_95] == "1") { $wa[custom_97] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_97]);?>
                    {src:'images/Home-Pages-Angkor-PC.png'},
                <? } ?>
                {src:'images/Home-Pages-Peakbond.png'}
            ]
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php (esp. see comment #1)

Comment: I'm afraid that it's not working for me. Can you please show me based on the that i given. I've try but it doesn't work.

Comment: See the edit above.

Comment: Hi Aydin, i have figure the syntaxt. Thanks for your time and reply. Really apprecite it. Cheers.